# $http inside a promise success callback not executing Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have the following code:

```
$scope.remove = function( smallGroupTypeId, smallGroupTypeIndex, $event ) {
    $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: BASE_URL + "/small-group-type/" + smallGroupTypeId + "/delete",
        headers: { 
            "Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 
        }
    })
    .success( function( data ) {
        if ( data.success == true ) {
            toastr.success('Message', data.message);
            $scope.smallGroupTypes.splice( smallGroupTypeIndex, 1 );
            var tr = angular.element( $event.currentTarget.closest( "tr" ) ) ;
            tr.remove();
            $scope.search()
        } else {
            toastr.success('Message', data.message);
        }
    });
};
```

This code deletes an item and then success function it should call the search() function which inside it is another $http call. However, I got into success function but the $scope.search() never executed.

This is my $scope.search():

```
    $scope.search = function( otherParams, $event ) {
    SearchFactory.search( $scope.searchCallback, otherParams, $event );
};
```

This is my SearchFactory.search() code:

```
factory.search = function ( callback, otherParams, $event ) {

    $rootScope.otherParams = angular.merge({}, $rootScope.otherParams , otherParams);

    if (typeof $rootScope.otherParams == "undefined") {
        $rootScope.otherParams = {};
    }

    if (typeof otherParams != "undefined" && typeof otherParams.sort != "undefined") {
        factory.toggleSortingDirection( $event );
    } else {
        factory.pageActive( $event );
    }

    var params = angular.extend( {}, $( "form" ).serializeObject(), $rootScope.otherParams );

    $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: URI,
        params:  params,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
    }).then( function( response ) {
        callback(angular.fromJson(response.data.items), angular.fromJson(response.data.data));
    });
};
```

Why is that so?

Thanks.

Comment: enters if (data.success ==true )?

Comment: FYI `success` and `error` are deprecated, use `then` and `catch` instead. Also be aware any chained promises after wont wait for your nested `$http` call as your not returning any promises.

Comment: yes it enters. It worked when i tried to remove a directive which has $compile on it. But i need that directive. So may theres another solution?

Comment: How did you declare `$scope.search()`?

Comment: ill edit my code to include the $scope.search function.

Comment: Try using `then` instead of `success`

Comment: i do not have access to response if i used then()

Comment: you have to use $q to make custom promise and return promise from then and you will get response. `var deferred = $q.defer(); ` and inside then() success use `deferred.resolve(data);` and at last return `deferred.promise`